# Get names in Pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame of log-data looking like this:

```
date    url users
0   2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=001 45
1   2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=002 12
2   2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=003 17
3   2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=004 87
4   2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=005 4
```

I need to extract the top three urls by visitors per day.

If I do this:

```
df.groupby(['date'])['users'].nlargest(3)
```

I almost get what I want:

```
2019-09-12  183    88
            132    62
            49     41
2019-09-13  275    95
            336    65
            206    18
```

However, instead of the numbers, 183, 132 and so forth, I need the url like this:

```
2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=001    88
            http://example.com/?url=002    62
            http://example.com/?url=003    41
2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=004    95
            http://example.com/?url=002    65
            http://example.com/?url=001    18
```

If I add url like this:

```
df.groupby(['date','url'])['users'].nlargest(3)
```

I lose the url-info completely. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('url').groupby(['date'])['users'].nlargest(3)
print (df)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
date        url                        
2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=004    87
            http://example.com/?url=001    45
            http://example.com/?url=003    17
Name: users, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `ascending=[True, False]` and [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['date', 'users'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('date').head(3)
```

Test in changed data:

```
print (df)
         date                          url  users
0  2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=001     45
1  2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=002     12
2  2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=003     17
3  2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=004     87
4  2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=005      4

df1 = df.set_index('url').groupby(['date'])['users'].nlargest(3)
print (df1)
date        url                        
2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=001    45
            http://example.com/?url=002    12
2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=004    87
            http://example.com/?url=003    17
            http://example.com/?url=005     4
Name: users, dtype: int64

df2 = df.sort_values(['date', 'users'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('date').head(3)
print (df2)
         date                          url  users
0  2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=001     45
1  2019-09-12  http://example.com/?url=002     12
3  2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=004     87
2  2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=003     17
4  2019-09-13  http://example.com/?url=005      4
```